# Deriving the standard equation for a damped sine wave

Tags: calculus

I am aware that the equation for a damped sine wave is $x(t)=Ae^{-pt}\cos(wt+\theta)$ where $p$ is a decay constant.

Does anyone know how to derive this equation using superposition or perhaps another method?

Answer (score 1):

I know two main methods:

Either use complex analysis and Euler's formula, saying that $x(t)/A = Re(e^{t\cdot(-p + i\omega) + i\theta})$ and you just derive an exponential as $Re(f')=(Re(f))'$ and $(e^{\alpha t})' = \alpha \cdot e^{\alpha t}$.

The second way is to differentiate using product rule.
Let $u$ and $v$ be two functions.
$(u\cdot v)' = u' \cdot v + v' \cdot u$
In this case, $u = e^{-pt}$ and $v=cos(\omega t + \theta)$.